# Plotting sigmoid function in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am new to Mathematica.

I want to write my own sigmoid function where I can give coefficients to `e` and `x`. When plotting, I don't get any output, what could be the problem?

```
sigmoid_f[x_, a_, b_] := 1/(1 + ae^-bx)
Plot[sigmoid_f[x, 1, 1], {x, -5, 5}]
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do not use underscores in names; they have special meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect that when you write

```
sigmoid_f[x_, a_, b_] := 1/(1 - ae^-bx)
```

you mean to write

```
sigmoidf[x_, a_, b_] := 1/(1 - a*E^(-b*x))
```

where `E` is the built-in representation of Euler's number and `*` is the usual text form for the multiplication operator.

Also, as @Alan commented, don't use `_` in the names of objects you define.

Mathematica is extremely particular about matters of case and punctuation.  In your original expression `ae` and `bx` are both names of (presumably unknown) objects.